# Ubuntu 18.04 freezing for a second or two randomly

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome, bug-reporting

I've installed ubuntu 18.04 in my (new) laptop. Its running very smoothly, but I have a very minor(?) problem.

When I'm browsing with chrome, (with lots of tabs; memory usage around 8 ~ 10 GB) my laptop gets unresponsive for a second or two, out of nowhere. And then its okay. After a couple of minutes, this repeats. During this period, it seems that I can move my mouse, but clicking doesn't work; I can't type in my keyboard as well, but it seems to remember what I've typed a few seconds ago. What's strange is, when I'm playing games like Dota 2, I don't find any noticeable lags though.

Laptop specs :

MSI gaming notebook

CPU : i7 8750H

GPU : Nvidia 1050 Ti, using nvidia driver 390

RAM : 16 GB RAM

SSD : M.2 250 GB + 500 GB, both are LUKS encrypted

With Chrome running, I did a few diagnosos. (Chrome using 7 GB RAM)

- Looking at sensors, its running comfortably at 45 ~ 47 degrees celsius.
- Looking at the system monitor, it appears that one thread hits 100% when there's this lag. Normally, my CPU usage is pretty low, except one thread hitting ~50%-ish occasionally.
- So, when I looked at dmesg, I saw things like

[53066.013838] CPU8: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 11192)

There are multiple lines mentioning it. It seems to me that temp is above threshold for a few milliseconds. I'm not sure if this message is related to my freeze, but it looks like they are.

This is weird - as my CPU isn't overheating at all.

Is there any way to fix this error? It is quite frustrating actually.

Comment: Running Linux on gaming laptop. That's unusual. Well regarding the issue you mentioned. You need to mention specifically which programs are taking 100% of your CPU

Comment: Since at that time chrome, gedit, terminal and system monitor were running, I believe it is chrome. Anyways, is there a way to keep track of my CPU% with programs?